# Get value of another property in same object nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I the following code in my hapijs (nodejs) project

```
var t = require('joi');
var bdd = require('./../bdd');

module.exports = [
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/getAllParties',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
          //some code
    },
    config:{
        description: this.path + " route."
    }
}
];
```

But when a load my route i see :

> : description = undefined route. ...

How do I set this value ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example `this` doesn't refer to the object you're trying to export. What you could do is use a function at this point called `getConfig` to return an object with that information:

```
module.exports = [{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/getAllParties',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        //some code
    },
    getConfig: function () {
        return {
            description: this.path + " route."
        }
    }
}]


obj[0].getConfig().description; // "/getAllParties route."
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/289t7atp/)

Comment: i can change the structure ... this is for hapijs (with mrHorse), i try description : function(){ return this.path}
but my application doesn' t start

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: its a nodejs application not standard javascript ...
and this object is for hapijs ( http://hapijs.com/ )
with your solution i have a error :  " description is not a string "

Answer (score -1):

**You missed the ];**

```
var t = require('joi');
var bdd = require('./../bdd');

module.exports = [
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/getAllParties',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
          //some code
    },
    config:{
        description: this.path + " route."
    }
}
```

Comment: Not in my code, juste on my copy/past